# Parcel Bundler beautify, lint, and create .min.js

Tags: javascript, lint, parceljs

I'm new the world of automating/testing/bunding with JS and I've got parcel setup for the most part but I noticed that when it builds files, it does not actually save them with the `.min.js` part in the file name. I'm wondering if theres a way to do this without having to rename the build file manually.

I'm also trying to find a way to have parcel go through the original source files(the ones that you work on) and lint and beautify them for me

Here's what my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "lpac",
  "version": "1.3.1",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "parcel watch --no-hmr",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "targets": {
    "lite-maps": {
      "source": ["./path/file1.js", "./path/file2.js", "./path/file3.js"],
      "distDir": "./path/build/"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
  "outputFormat" : "global",
}
```

I checked out the docs but I couldn't find anything on linting or beautifying with parcel. How can i go about doing that? If you have tutorial links to doing so please also share because resources/tutorials seem scarce for anything other than the basic watching and building files

Comment: Are your source files (the ones that you work on) prefixed with `.min.js`, and you want this extension to be preserved by parcel in the out put files? Or are you wanting parcel to _add_ the `.min` part to the output file (e.g. `index.js` (source) => `index.min.js` (parcel output))

Comment: @AndrewStegmaier I want it to add  `.min.js` to the file names automatically since it minifies them just fine, but they're the same name after being built

I've seen other bundlers like webpack and rollup i think automatically rename the file to .min.js/.min.css after minifying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no out-of-the-box setting that can cause parcel javascript output look like `[fileName].[hash].min.js` instead of `[fileName].[hash].js`. The `.min.js` extension is just a convention to keep output files distinct from source files, though - it has no effect at runtime - and the fact that parcel does [automatic content hashing](https://parceljs.org/features/production/#content-hashing) makes it easy enough to tell this. And even though they don't have a `.min.js` extension, these output files are definitely still [minified and optimized by default](https://parceljs.org/features/production/).

However, if you really, really want this anyways, it's relatively simple to write a [Namer plugin](https://parceljs.org/plugin-system/namer/) for parcel that adds `.min.js` to all javascript output:

Here's the code:

```js
import { Namer } from "@parcel/plugin";
import path from "path";

export default new Namer({
  name({ bundle }) {
    if (bundle.type === "js") {
      const filePath = bundle.getMainEntry()?.filePath;
      if (filePath) {
        let baseNameWithoutExtension = path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath));
        // See: https://parceljs.org/plugin-system/namer/#content-hashing
        if (!bundle.needsStableName) {
          baseNameWithoutExtension += "." + bundle.hashReference;
        }
        return `${baseNameWithoutExtension}.min.js`;
      }
    }
    // Returning null means parcel will keep the name of non-js bundles the same.
    return null;
  },
});
```

Then, supposing the above code was published in a package called `parcel-namer-js-min`, you would add it to your parcel pipeline with this `.parcelrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "namers": ["parcel-namer-js-min", "..."]
}
```

Here is [an example repo where this is working](https://github.com/astegmaier/stackoverflow-parcel-namer).

The answer to your second question (is there "a way to have parcel go through the original source files(the ones that you work on) and lint and beautify them for me") is unfortunately, no.

However, parcel can work well side-by-side with other command line tools that do this do this. For example, I have most of my projects set up with a `format` command in the `package.json`, that looks like this:

```
{
   ...
   "scripts": {
      ...
      "format": "prettier --write src/**/* -u --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern"
   }
   ...
{
```

You can easily make that command automatically run for git commits and pushes with [husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/).